# How to equivalent to ps -ef in Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, powershell, gnu, gdb

I have looked online, and have not found anything that would accomplish what I want to do. I am looking for a command with output equivalent to "ps -ef" of Linux so I can find out the process id associated with an executable I created myself. I want to do this so can attach the GDB debugger to it. I am doing this on a windows 10 machine. I found out about get-process in powershell, but the output does not show me the name of the executable like ps command does. Can anyone help? I am trying to follow [these](http://returntojava.blogspot.com/2008/11/overcome-java-jni-gdb-errors-on.html) procedures.

Here is the type of output I am after:

```
B$ ps -ef
...
user     17809 16492  7 21:28 pts/1    00:00:00 java JNITest
user     17821 14042  4 21:28 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
user     17845 17821  0 21:28 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Thanks. You were both right. I had to look for "java".

Comment: [tasklist](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) - TaskList displays all running applications and services with their Process ID (PID) This can be run on either a local or a remote computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use powershell rather than the typical cmd prompt.  Just type powershell to open up a term.  Then in powershell type Get-Process to list all processes.  To get a specific process do Get-Process -Id 99.  Of course 99 would be your PID.